# I can't derive a formula for writing from a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional one

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, sparse-matrix

I encountered a problem converting a two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional one. From a two-dimensional array you need to write out only those elements that are under the main diagonal on odd lines and those that are above the main diagonal on even lines. I can't figure out the formula for calculating the index in a one-dimensional array. We need to fix the NewIndex function, which is where the index of an element in a one-dimensional array is calculated

Here is the program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N 6

int NewIndex(int x, int y) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        j += (i % 2 == 0) ? N - i : N - i - 1;
    }
    return j + y - x;
}

void Put(int vec[], int x, int y, int v) {

    if ((x % 2 == 1 && x < y) || (x % 2 == 0 && x > y))
        return;
   
    vec[NewIndex(x, y)] = v;
}

int Get(int vec[], int x, int y) {
    if ((x % 2 == 1 && x < y) || (x % 2 == 0 && x > y))
        return 0;

    return vec[NewIndex(x, y)];
}

void RandArray(int a[N][N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (i % 2 == 1 && i < j)
                a[i][j] = 0;
            else if (i % 2 == 0 && i > j)
                a[i][j] = 0;
            else
                a[i][j] = rand() % 50;
        }
    }
}

void PrintArray(int a[N][N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%3i", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int vec[N * 4];
    int array[N][N];
    RandArray(array);

    printf("Original Matrix:\n");
    PrintArray(array);


    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            Put(vec, i, j, array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N * 4; i++)
        printf("%3i", vec[i]);

    printf("\nSparse Matrix:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            printf("%3i", Get(vec, i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Conclusion so far:

```
Original Matrix:
 19  8 21 23 47 15
 39 46  0  0  0  0
  0  0 34  2 32 13
 44  0 26 36  0  0
  0  0  0  0 15 34
 33 21 29 45 11 12

 19  8 21 23 47 39 46-858993460-858993460-858993460 34 44  0 33 21 29 45 11 12-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460
Sparse Matrix:
 19  8 21 23 47 39
 39 46  0  0  0  0
  0  0 34 44  0 33
 44  0 33 21  0  0
  0  0  0  0 45 11
 33 21 29 45 11 12
```

Expected output:

```
Original Matrix:
 19  8 21 23 47 15
 39 46  0  0  0  0
  0  0 34  2 32 13
 44  0 26 36  0  0
  0  0  0  0 15 34
 33 21 29 45 11 12

 19  8 21 23 47 15 39 46 34 2 32 13 44 0 26 36 15 34 33 21 29 45 11 12

Sparse Matrix:
 19  8 21 23 47 15
 39 46  0  0  0  0
  0  0 34  2 32 13
 44  0 26 36  0  0
  0  0  0  0 15 34
 33 21 29 45 11 12
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? Why do you care about the index of 1D array at all? Can't you go through the matrix row-wise until diagonal (`row_idx<=col_idx`) and just append to the array?

Comment: Is 'writing it all in sequence' not an option?

Comment: A minor issue: the text say "under" and "above" the diagonal, but the expected output also shows the elements *on* the diagonal. Which one is correct?

Comment: `int NewIndex(int x, int y) { return y*N + x; }` Assuming that `N` is the width of the 2d array.

Comment: Also, `vec[N*4]` is too short of a buffer to contain `N*N` elements (where `N` is `6`).

Comment: Why did you tag C++, when every single line of your snippet is written in C? This is not how C++ deals with collections.

Comment: "Converting a two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional one" and "From a two-dimensional array you need to write out only those elements that are under the main diagonal on odd lines and those that are above the main diagonal on even lines." are two very different problems. Do you need to solve both?

Answer (score 0):

The relation you are looking for is:

```
#include <cstddef>
template<std::size_t Width, std::size_t Height>
std::size_t index_of(std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    return y*Width + x;
    // or return x*Height + y; depending on your cache optimization, might be off topic
}

// Example usage:
#include <array>
constexpr std::size_t Width = 10;
constexpr std::size_t Height = 10;
std::array<int, Width * Height> matrix;
matrix[index_of<Width, Height>(2, 6)] = 42;
```

---

Not directly related: you might be interested to look into classes, member-functions (a/k/a methods) and unit tests.

---

Now you can define a template class composed of a simple `std::array`, overloading `operator()` to return the multi-dimensional object. Its usage would be:

```
Matrix<int, 10, 10> matrix;
matrix(3, 8) = 42;
```

Comment: @Constantinos Glynos Amended my comment on code quality. You interpreted that in a way I did not intend to project.

Comment: Thank you. I understand sometimes written word can be misinterpreted. :-)